# php из odbc в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Есть конструкция:

```
   $sql ="SELECT vid.name, vid.id FROM vid";
   $result=odbc_exec($conn, $sql);    
while(list($v1, $v2) = record($result))
    {...
```

Переписываю ее для mysql

```
   $sql ="SELECT vid.name, vid.id FROM vid";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);      
while(list($v1, $v2) = record($result))
    {...
```

Вопрос в том что после переделки в переменных `$v1` и `$v2` один и тотже `vid.name` хотя в `$v2` должно быть `vid.id`

Comment: А что такое `record`? Я че-то о таком не слышал ни разу, посмотрите документацию [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php), там есть пример как значения из выборки можно получать. И расширение `mysql_*` устарело, как минимум надо `mysqli_*` использовать, либо PDO/ORM

Comment: record в варианте odbc 
`function record($resId){
   $mpResult = odbc_fetch_array($resId);
   if(is_array($mpResult)) {
       return array_values($mpResult);
   }
   return false;
}`

Comment: Читайте, куда вас BOPOH послал. И обратите внимание на предупреждение выделенное розовым цветом!

Comment: @maix, переписывайте функцию `record` для работы с `mysql` и будет вам счастье.